# Bootstrap how to leave text unresponsive but within div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the mobile device the text is like this:

[image]

but I need it to stay like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The code I'm using:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:#071885;">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">     
            <h1 style="color: #000;font-weight: bold;background: gold;font-size: 24px; padding: 5px;">
            LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE
            </h1>
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I already tried `no-wrap` but that did not work.

**UPDATE:**

@kukkuz

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox for this:

1. Set `display: inline-flex` on the row and make use of the fact that an *inline element will extend to its contents*.
2. Now you can use `text-nowrap` class or `white-space: nowrap` to get the effect that you need - see demo below:

```css
.row {
  display: inline-flex; /* ensures the text stays inside */
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 100vw; /* sets 100% width in desktop */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:#071885;">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1 style="color: #000;font-weight: bold;background: gold;font-size: 24px; padding: 5px;">
        LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, I went back to work on it just now, sorry for the delay in answering. That still did not solve the problem. It turns out that the way you proposed is unconfigured. I updated my question, please see

Comment: can you update your code as well as create a snippet / jsfiddle so that we can help you :)

Comment: you only need *one* `container-fluid` class in a bootstrap page...  See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9utgryd5/) - you can use `display: inline-block` to get the desired effect

Comment: also add the jsfiddle code you gave me to your question, I'll update answer accordingly if this works for you...

Answer (score 0):

remove this class `col-md-12` and set styles that you want

Comment: even taking out the class `col-md-12` the result is the first image. What style should I add so that the text stays inside the `container-fluid` div but the container fluid div fits the text and not the text if it fits the container